# Rsync Issue (AWS EC2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, amazon-ec2

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to Rsync from a remote to a local machine but been having issues with finding the synced files apparently.

The command I entered is:

```
sync -avzhe "~/var/test2/*" -e "ssh -i /etc/nginx/WhatsDue.pem" ubuntu@ec2********.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/test/
```

The command seems to be running properly:

```
    receiving incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x          4.10K 2015/02/25 19:15:48 .
-rwxrwxrwx             11 2015/02/25 19:15:48 test222.txt

sent 20 bytes  received 66 bytes  34.40 bytes/sec
total size is 11  speedup is 0.13
```

However, when I go to the "~/var/test2/" folder, I can't find the test222.txt file there.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: is there /var/test2 at all present on local machine ?

Comment: yes. I just entere the following command:

sudo rsync -avzh -e  "ssh -i /etc/nginx/***.pem" /var/test2/* ubuntu@ec2-*****.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/test/

And got the following result:

sending incremental file list
tester.txt
rsync: mkstemp "/var/test/.tester.txt.n7vYn6" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 101 bytes  received 116 bytes  144.67 bytes/sec
total size is 8  speedup is 0.04
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]

Comment: are the permissions for /var/test/.tester.txt.n7vYn6 same as for user with whom you are perfomring ssh inside rsync